# No visual interface on ubuntu 12.10 after installing updates

Tags: installation, boot, ubuntu-tweak, cairo

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer and somewhere between running the updates and installing Unsettings, Cairo, and Ubuntu tweak; the system asks to restart.

After that there is no visual interface, just terminal. It asks me for my login information but without visual interface.

I have reinstalled a couple of times because I was getting a error after running the updates. Last time I got past the error by updating with terminal. It asked me to restart after running cairo and then I have no visual interface again.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the terminal with your username and password and when you get to the bash prompt enter:

```
startx
```

Post any errors that pop up.

```
 install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

then reconfigure the driver

```
dpkg-reconfigure fglrx-updates
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, here are the errors that I see:

Comment: Loading estension GLX
FATAL: Module fglrx_updates not found.
(WW) fglrx: No matchin Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
FATAL: Module fglrx_updates not found.

Fatal server error:
no screens found
(EE)
Please consult the X.Org Foundation support
    at http://wiki.x.org
for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for aditional information.
(EE)
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error

Comment: I reinstalled again. Has the problem something to do with installing the video driver? if so, how can I do that? I tried to do it with sudo apt-get install jockey-kde and the running jockey, but it told me that my video driver could not be installed or updated